# Best way to partial group by for grouping last/first X docs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Is there any Aggregation Pipeline Stage that can help with grouping some of the results, as following:

```
{ "_id": "some-id-1", "sum": 14.49 }
{ "_id": "some-id-2", "sum": 12.49 }
{ "_id": "some-id-3", "sum": 9.99 }
{ "_id": "some-id-4", "sum": 8.49 }
{ "_id": "some-id-5", "sum": 7.49 }
```

so it will group only the documents coming after record #3? for ex.:

```
{ "_id": "some-id-1", "sum": 14.49 }
{ "_id": "some-id-2", "sum": 12.49 }
{ "_id": "some-id-3", "sum": 9.99 }
{ "_id": "grouped", "sum": 15.98 } <---- partial group by
```

I was looking at `$bucket` but it seems to be helpful just if the `sum` is known in advance.

The idea is to reduce the amount of data mongodb has to ship back when there's a huge result set.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with using `$facet`:

```
{ 
   $facet: {
    list: [ {
      $limit: 3
    } ],
    other: [
      { $skip: 3 },
      { $group: {
        _id: 'other',
        sum: {$sum: '$sum'},
      } },
      ],
  }
}
```